# Error saving data in Firebase - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, formik

I had a code with Expo 45 but now the SDK does not allow me that version so I had to update to the latest version to avoid future errors in the versions and I updated it to version 48 of Expo, this code worked correctly and was always saved in the Firebase database but now that it has been updated to the latest version, just like React AND React Native, it no longer allows me to save the data in the database.

```
    "expo": "45.0.0",
    "firebase": "9.7.0",
    "formik": "2.2.9",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "luxon": "^3.0.4",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "1.8.0",
    "uuid": "8.3.2",
    "yup": "0.32.11"
```

But it has stopped working with these versions

```
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "firebase": "9.7.0",
    "formik": "2.2.9",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "luxon": "^3.0.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "1.8.0",
    "uuid": "8.3.2",
    "yup": "0.32.11"
```

I can no longer save data to the Firebase Database and the only thing that has changed between versions is React and React Native. I can't find an explanation, I can't find the error either

```
import React from "react";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { useFormik } from "formik";

export const Modal = (props) => {

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: initialValues(),
    validationSchema: validationSchema(),
    onSubmit: async (formValue) => {
      try {
        const auth = getAuth();
        const idReview = uuid();
        const newData = formValue;
        newData.id = idReview;
        newData.idPlace = id;
        newData.idPhone = auth.currentUser.phoneNumber;
        newData.idUser = auth.currentUser.uid;
        newData.avatar = auth.currentUser.photoURL;
        newData.displayName = auth.currentUser.displayName;
        newData.create = new Date();
        await setDoc(doc(db, "reviews", idReview), newData);
        close();
        Toast.show({
          text1: "Se publicó correctamente tu comentario.",
        });
      } catch (error) {
        Toast.show({
          text1: "Sucedió un error. Inténtalo más tarde.",
        });
      }
    },
  });

  return (
    <>
      <PrevModal show={showModal} close={closeModal}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={[{ padding: 10, paddingTop: 20 }]}>
            <Text
              style={[
                {
                  color: "#5f6368",
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                  fontSize: 12,
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  alignItems: "center",
                },
              ]}
            >
              Las opiniones son públicas y contienen la información de tu
              cuenta.
            </Text>
          </View>

          <Input
            placeholder="Descripción obligatoria"
            onChangeText={(text) => formik.setFieldValue("comment", text)}
            errorMessage={formik.errors.comment}
            multiline={true}
          />

          <Button
            title="Publicar"
            containerStyle={styles.btnContainer}
            buttonStyle={styles.btn}
            onPress={formik.handleSubmit}
            loading={formik.isSubmitting}
          />
        </View>
      </PrevModal>
    </>
  );
};
```

I updated the versions of the packages and I could no longer save in the firebase database.